# ffmpeg: av_interleaved_write_frame(): Protocol error

Tags: ffmpeg, video

GoPro cameras cut up video in 4GB MP4 files.

Attempting to merge them with ffmpeg 4.4.4 like so:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in *.MP4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.mp4
```

Merging multiple such files worked before (with older versions of ffmpeg), but this time ends up with a failure:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5606724781c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter34x      
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Protocol errorime=00:09:29.42 bitrate=60189.7kbits/s speed=1.38x    
Error writing trailer of output.mp4: Protocol error
frame=34215 fps= 83 q=-1.0 Lsize= 4194048kB time=00:09:30.81 bitrate=60190.4kbits/s speed=1.38x    
video:4181248kB audio:13195kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

In the block above, "av_interleaved_write_frame(): Protocol error" is printed on top of the stat line, seemingly blending with that text.
In the whole output, this text shows up in red:

```
Application provided duration: -9223372036854775808 / timestamp: -9223372036854775808 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Protocol error
Error writing trailer of output.mp4: Protocol error
```

The input files see to be valid and play just fine in players, the output file does not.
What could cause this, how could it be fixed?

Update: when it fails, the output file is 4GB, and that is a FAT32 filesystem. Looks like it's a file size limit being hit, and the error message not being that obvious.

Comment: Why ffmpeg 4.4.4? Did you try upgrading?

Comment: That's a good question - I had ffmpeg-4 installed, probably a sign of when this OpenSUSE Tumbleweed box was set up. Upgraded to ffmpeg-6, but it still fails - the red lines changed to "av_interleaved_write_frame(): Protocol error
Error muxing a packet
Error writing trailer: Protocol error". But there's something I noticed just now... when it fails, the output file is 4GB, and that is a FAT32 filesystem...

Comment: Please update the question with additional details instead of just commenting. But yeah, you pretty much "solved" it then.

Comment: Thanks, will do once I have it confirmed for sure.